# What is the meaning of then in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the sentence

> The first documented WNV case in Kerala was in Alappuzha in 2011, with the numbers **then** growing.

What does **then** mean in this sentence?

What I think is-
Here **then** is used as an adverb that **refers to a particular time**.I interpret it this way-

> The first documented WNV case in Kerala was in Alappuzha in 2011, **and the population of this virus was rising at that time(in 2011)**.

But I am not sure if I am correct. Help me understand it better.
Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1):

It means that after 2011, more cases of WNV occurred

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.